# Bad Request error while using google drive api to copy file into a folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to use the google drive api to copy a file into a folder

As the documentation says i am generating a POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}/copy?access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

i am using python to generate the request and in order to specify the target folder i am setting the  request body to -

```
{
"parents":
[
{
"id":"{parent_id}"
}
]
}
```

so the final code is like-

```
url = https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/Ansjd021-23123414kjn2k3jn2/copy?access_token=Ya.asdsakjn2312k3n21kj3n-12312j3knb123l
body = {
    "parents":
        [
            {
                "id":"ZXC12312323123-Blahasd12323X"
            }
        ]
}
request2 = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(body))
request2_open = urllib2.urlopen(request2)
response = request2_open.read()
request2_open.close()
print response
```

The problem being that I am getting a Http Error : 404 Bad Request
I cant seem to figure out the problem with this. I am doing the same thing using the google playground and its running there.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#try-it and got ...

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1234/copy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZSZB-t4b4HsR5
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "parents": [
  {
   "id": "1234"
  }
 ]
}
```

This looks pretty much the same as your sample, except the authtoken is in an http header rather than the URL. Also, what happens if you don't urlencode the body? Is there a longer error message in the response body?

Comment: Its mentioned in the API docs that you can pass the access_token in the URL OR in the headers. Same error(BAD request) is thrown in case i don't urlencode the body.
Surprisingly though using httplib2 solved the issue. I don't know how but it did.